# Airflow: Can you put descriptions of the tasks so that they show up in dashboard?

Tags: airflow

I can't seem to find a way to put descriptions about the Airflow tasks so that they show up in the Dashboard. I am reading their documentation but can't find there either. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can document both DAGs and tasks with either `doc` or `doc_<json|yaml|md|rst>` fields depending on how you want it formatted. These will show up on the dashboard under "Graph View" for DAGs and "Task Details" for tasks.

Example:

```py
"""
# Foo
Hello, these are DAG docs.
"""

...

dag = DAG(
    'test.foo',
    default_args=default_args,
)
dag.doc_md = __doc__

with dag:
    task1 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='task1',
    )
    task1.doc_md = 'Hi, these are task docs.'
```

Which will result the following:

[image: dag_docs]

[image: task_docs]

This feature is documented in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#dag-task-documentation.